# Expanding a user card leads to unnecessary shifting the elements below

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, user-card

Is it possible to prevent shifting the web page items down on expanding the user card?

> [image: User card]

As you can notice, the "Add a comment" link, horizontal line, and the rest content of the page are shifted to the bottom on expanding the user card and goes back on collaption.